# Javascript Variable Reference when passing a Class as a Variable (PhpStorm)

Tags: javascript, jquery, phpstorm

Using PhpStorm: My code is passing a Instantiated Class as a Parameter into a function. I know that `className` is a reference to a particular class. But is there anyway to let my code become aware of what `ClassName` is?

```
   $(document).on('validSelection', function(event,className){
      alert( className.sayHello() );
   });
```

This would really make coding this particular function a lot easier since I plan on using `ClassName` a lot. In php, you can force the recognition by do somethings like:

```
/* @var $variable ClassName */
```

Comment: Do you mean className is a string containing the name of a class?

Comment: no. className is the class being passed as a parameter. so in this situation... `alert( className.helloWorld() );` would work.

Comment: Then... what do you mean, "become aware"? That's not really a sensible phrase to use in this context.

Comment: I should have been more clear. Was looking to have IDE "be aware" when I type `className.s`... `sayHello()` pops up in a fairly short list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My code is passing a Instantiated Class as a Parameter into a function

No, it isn't. You just added another parameter to the function's list, but when it's called (by jQuery, when the event happens), it's not passed. If you have access to `className` when you bind the event handler, you can just take advantage of the closure:

```
var className = {
    sayHello : function() {
       return "hello";
    }
};
$(document).on('validSelection', function(event){
   alert(className.sayHello()); // works
});
```

---

On the other hand: I see you're using a custom event. So, if you have a call to [`.trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) anywhere else on your code, then you can pass anything as the second argument, and it will be passed to the event handler:

```
var className = {
    sayHello : function() {
       return "hello";
    }
};
$(document).trigger('validSelection', className);

// On a separate scope...

$(document).on('validSelection', function(event, className){
   alert(className.sayHello()); // works
});
```

Comment: My question was more related to the IDE (PhpStorm) being smart enough to know that 'ClassName' included 'SayHello()'  .. But I think this question is spurred by my discovery of `trigger()` because at least in this case, the trigger is defined not knowing all the areas of code that might reference it. which is incredibly useful. Thank you for all you help on this!

Comment: Oh sorry, my brain just skipped the references the the IDE on your question. I hope my answer can be still useful for somebody else.

Comment: yeah. I think it was a reality check to what I was doing and thinking about as well.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript we don't have classes but use "prototypes" to act like we do. So to check the "classness" of an object you need to use one of the prototype methods.

If you've got a readily-referable instantiated copy of the `className` object hanging around you can use `className.prototype.constructor` and check if it [`isPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf) that other object.

Alternatively, you can check if that `className` is an [`instanceOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) some prototypical object.